# Dropbox OAuth API v2 not working on Google Cloud Platform - Datalab - iPython Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dropbox-api, google-cloud-datalab

Referring to the tutorial at [Dropbox for Python Developers](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial)

I am using Google Cloud Platform, datalab.

CODE:

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(<s_dropbox_access_token_v2>)
dbx.users_get_current_account()
```

OUTPUT:

```
ValueError: Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=30, read=30, total=None), but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with the requests library. It looks like this was fixed in requests itself, so please update to the latest version. The latest version of the requests library is currently 2.18.2.